# Does the JVM intercept disk transactions/have its own disk buffer?

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronization, berkeley-db

**Question:**

Do you guys know if calls to write on disk are intercepted by the jvm? Does it have its own buffer between the application and the OS? More specifically, can the jvm make an asynchronous disk write operation look synchronous to the application?

**Background:**

I've been running some applications with Berkeley DB, in sync mode, that is, the database is supposed to return calls to `db.put(key, value)` only after the `(key, value)` pair has been safely persisted to disk. To set such options, I do:

```
envConfig.setDurability(Durability.COMMIT_SYNC);
dbConfig.setDeferredWrite(false);
```

Above, `envConfig` is an `EnvironmentConfig` object and `dbconfig` is a `DatabaseConfig` object, which I use to adjust the behavior of the database.

Anyway, the above configuration is supposed to make every `put(...)` call to cause a disk transaction (which you can measure, i.e., with `iostat` on Linux), right? This would be because the alternative (COMMIT_NO_SYNC with deferred write) would return calls to `put` without waiting for the disk, so that it could buffer a good amount of data to write all at once, improving performance, at the expense of safety.

**Problem:**

I'm making several thousands of calls to `put` per second, but the number of disk transactions per second does not change almost, whether or not I set the above options in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing an exact answer of the problem. But here is my experience with disk operations. In past I have faced the problem, where my expectation of a disk operation no fulfilled on stipulated time.

The disk write is always much much slower than writing into memory. I guess the disk writing here depends on hardware, native OS API and CPU allocation being given to disk write operation. So, you should not expect the disk write be as fast as you method call. In fact no program logic should be written assuming certain performance parameter of any devices like printer, disk etc.

If you meant to do that, you must have a reconciliation method, which ensure that the operation would be 100% completed, before next operation could be done.